# Parse SQL to sql builder

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, querydsl, jooq

Is there easy way to convert SQL string like:

```
SELECT u.name, u.role 
FROM users 
WHERE user_id = ?
```

to any of SQL builders like JOOQ, QueryDsl just to get ability to modify query — add joins, additional "where" clauses, LIMIT-OFFSET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option, I've used [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) in the past for a project like this.  It wasn't very difficult to use.

Comment: Thank you! Found following [example](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-building#extending-a-simple-insert) in their wiki. Looks promising

Answer (score 2):

#### jOOQ's Parser

jOOQ's more recent versions have introduced a parser, which parses arbitrary SQL from all currently supported vendor dialects into the jOOQ expression tree. Once you have that expression tree, you can manipulate it to whatever you want using the [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) SPI.

#### For historic context:

For jOOQ, there exists a third-party contribution by [Gudu Software](http://www.sqlparser.com/) called [SQL 2 jOOQ](https://github.com/sqlparser/sql2jooq), which can parse SQL `SELECT` statements written in either MySQL or PostgreSQL dialects and generate jOOQ code as output.

Comment: I would like to get objects, not code to create these objects

Comment: @zhogov: I had thought so but I still wanted to add the answer in case a future vistor finds this question...